# Creating/generating files in a mounted volume on docker container own to regular user and not to root

Tags: docker, permissions, volumes

The **Problem**: can't generate/create files on mounted volumes in docker that is not own by root. Throwing permission denied errors when I create and push my user to docker-compose as well.

**Scenario**:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: /home/john/clone_repository_and_generate_reports.sh 
    volumes:
      - "/home/john/:/home/john/"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    env_file:
      - ./.config.env
```

- My `docker-compose.yml` file calls to simple bash script that clones a github repository and generate different reports in python, In addition I want this data to be accessible and persistent to user `john`, unfortunately the the saved files are on `root` only.
- If Im adding on Dockerfile additional user `RUN addgroup -S developer && adduser -S john -G developer` It gets permissions issue accessing to this mounted volume with `user: john` attribute on docker-compose.yml file

**Expected behaviour**: cloned github repository and generated files owned by `john` and **not** by `root`.

What is the right approach dealing with permission issue on docker?
How can I save these files under `john` user on this mounted volume?

Comment: Is the problem that the mounted directory within the container is not accessible by user `john`, or is the problem that the generated directory on the host is owned by `root`?

Comment: The mounted directory is accessible though not writeable to John, Creation/modification of files are set only be root.

Comment: Can you just directly run `./clone_repository_and_generate_reports.sh`, without involving Docker?  That seems like it will do what you want: it will write directly to the host directory, as the current user, without any special configuration.  I'm not sure I see the benefit of trying to run this inside a bare `ubuntu` image with nothing installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: We need to run docker script on user scope and push the `user` attribute with user id and group id convention (`"uid:gid"` ).

**example**: run command in specific user `sudo -iu john`
and run docker-compose function:`USER_INFO=$(id -u):$(id -g) docker-compose up --build --force-recreate -d`

**compose file structure**:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: /home/john/clone_repository_and_generate_reports.sh 
    volumes:
      - "/home/john/:/home/john/"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    env_file:
      - ./.config.env
    user: "${USER_INFO}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a rule for user, so:
`user: john`

This is documented here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir